# Pyfasttest installation failure on Mac OS: fatal error: 'random' file not found

Tags: c++, python-3.x, macos, cython, fasttext

ERROR MESSAGES:
  src/pyfasttext.cpp:648:10: fatal error: 'random' file not found
  #include  . 
           ^~~~~~~~ . 
  1 warning and 1 error generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

---

Have installed gcc and LLVM...
UK-xxxx:vercheng$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.40.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

---

tried this: https://github.com/vrasneur/pyfasttext/issues/24
didn't help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, install Cython in order to install fasttext by this command:

`pip install Cython --install-option="--no-cython-compile"`

Now install fasttext using this command:

`pip install fasttext`